# calling recursively a function to create a list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to create a function that takes a list (even if `NULL`) and adds an element on top of the head.
I tried to do the following code, but I get a compilation error:

```
expected expression before ‘ListaDiElementi’
   crea(&ListaDiElementi lista);
```

my code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct elemento
{
    int info;
    struct element* next;
};

typedef struct element ElementOfList;
typedef ElementOfList * ListOfElements;

typedef ListOfElements crea (ListOfElements list)
{
    ListOfElements new = malloc (sizeof(ElementOfList));
    scanf("%d", &new->info);
    new->next=list;
    return new;
}
int main()
{
    ListOfElements list = NULL;
    do
    {
        crea(&ListOfElements list);
        printf("%d", list->info);
    }
    while(list->info>0);
}
```

I know this feels like "please do my code" but I am really stuck and I don't have any idea on how to do this.

Comment: it is wrong to put it out, it is specific in the slides we use, indeed gives you error

Comment: what is: `typedef ListOfElements crea (ListOfElements list)` and the associated code expected to perform?  as it is, it should not even compile

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `typedef ElementOfList * ListOfElements;`  This is trying to create a typedef of a typedef.  Much better to just declare an instance I.E.: `ElementOfList *ListOfElements;

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to pass the **type** in function call and also list is already a pointer so dont use **&**: So instead of

```
crea(&ListOfElements list);
```

use

```
crea(list);
```

Also **[typedef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef)** cannot be used in return type so the function signature should be:

```
ListOfElements crea (ListOfElements list){.....}
```